# Where should I start looking for a way to get a jumpstart on making a mobile design of my Rails 3 application?

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3, mobile, jquery-mobile, mobile-website, mobile-phones

Other than Google ;-) I have a Rails 3 application that allows users to drill-down by product category and subcategory to list products. There is a detailed product page that contains multiple images and lots of information. I will be "dumbing it down" significantly for the mobile site, but I'm not sure where to get started. Any help from anyone who has mobile-enabled a Rails application is deeply appreciated.

I make pretty heavy use of jQuery also in my app, and am willing to include it in the mobile app if necessary.

Comment: Awww... I was going to say Google. How about Amazon, then? They sell books there, and one of those books might cover this subject.

Comment: Books? ONLINE? That's crazy talk.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Jquery mobile just went into beta 1 a couple days ago. It's worth checking out in my opinion.

http://jquerymobile.com/

Answer (score 1):

If by 'mobile' you mean modern mobile browsers like Mobile Safari, then all you should need to do is to edit the CSS stylesheets to make the site look and fit better on a smaller screen (see 'responsive design').

Getting images to be responsive to a mobile environment is a little trickier. If they're not too big, or performance isn't a massive issue, then you could simply downscale them for the mobile browser.

Alternatively, there are a few other tricks to server smaller images to mobile browsers, and bigger ones to bigger screens - do some Googling for "responsive images" and you'll soon discover them.

Answer (score 1):

I use JQTouch, [JQTouch](http://jqtouch.com/) with Rails

To mimick the look and feel of a native app

[BMXMDB](http://iphone.bmxmdb.com)